# Jacoco report not showing coverage for one class after other dependency changes

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins, junit, jacoco

I had 100% coverage on my service project. However after few dependency upgrades to latest version, the jacoco report is showing ZERO coverage (Complete RED) for just ONE particular class while all unit test cases have successfully run without any failures. This is very strange and I am not getting any clue as to what would be the cause for this.

One thing I have noticed is that is this Warning in the Jenkins job just after the Unit Test execution:

```
12:17:58 Results :
12:17:58 
12:17:58 Tests run: 35, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
12:17:58 
12:17:58 [INFO] 
12:17:58 [INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.2:report (post-unit-test) @ myproject-service ---
12:17:58 [INFO] Loading execution data file /myproject-service-ci/workspace/myproject-service-job/myproject-service/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec
12:17:58 [INFO] Analyzed bundle 'myproject-service' with 8 classes
12:17:58 [WARNING] Classes in bundle 'myproject-service' do no match with execution data. For report generation the same class files must be used as at runtime.
12:17:58 [WARNING] Execution data for class com/abc/pqr/xyz/MyClassWithoutJacocoCoverage does not match.
```

The maven target command used in the jenkins job is:

`mvn clean -B -U -T 2 package pmd:pmd pmd:cpd findbugs:findbugs -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -DrunJacoco=true`

This test class uses  `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`. However there are many other test classes that are using PowerMockRunner and are getting covered.